# Tbody as Trow in Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table load with datatable plugin of bootstrap. We know that this datatable works usually to paginate the row numbers.

In my case, I need this datatable to paginate the tbody numbers.

```html
      <table border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th> No </th>
                 <th> Name </th>
                 <th> Mare </th>
              </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td rowspan="2"> 1 </td>
                 <td> Me </td>
                 <td> ! </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <th colspan="3"> Comment </th>
              </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td rowspan="2"> 2 </td>
                 <td> You </td>
                 <td> ! </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="3"> Comment </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>

          <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td rowspan="2"> 3 </td>
                 <td> We </td>
                 <td> ! </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td colspan="3"> Comment </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        
      </table>
```

Is it possible to achieve this with the datatable? Can anyone help, please?

Many Thanks in Advance.

Comment: After a quick read of the specification it looks as though multiple `tbody` elements are permitted within the table in the HTML5 specification, though I might have that wrong... or it might mean that tables are allowed to contain tables? Whichever is correct I do know that DataTables has an issue with `rowspan` and `colspan` so I think I'd be inclined to alter your markup to something a little different, maybe like this: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/mmh6o14e/ and hide the comment until it's required to be visible by the user - also in the JSFiddle above.

Comment: Is it possible to show all the hidden comment on document ready, so it is not hidden?

Comment: Still not overly happy with messing about with the structure and adding `colspan`s etc so how's this: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/mmh6o14e/2/ The text for the comment is abbreviated and is visible in a tooltipster (http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) tooltip on hover. The abbreviate function can be altered to allow more or less visible text. Hope that helps (and that you like cheese ;-) )